# How to convert time with time zone to timestamp?

Tags: python, pandas, timestamp

I have the following string `2020-06-12T00:00:03.084Z` in my DataFrame.

I need to convert this string to timestamp like in this format: `2020 6 12 00 00 03`.

I trying to do in this way but without good news:

`df['Time (UT)'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time (UT)'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')`

Comment: please include 1) the traceback, 2) `df.info()`, 3) `df.head().to_dict('list')`

Comment: What happens when you do it the way you said you did it?

Comment: `pd.to_datetime(['2020-06-12T00:00:03.084Z'])` worked as expected. Use `dt.strftime` to get your string after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using `dt.strptime` format:

```
df["Time (UT)"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Time(UT)"].dt.strftime('%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Since its a UTC time you need to specify the correct string format in to_datetime function. Since you have already written 80% format correct the only thing you need to add is the decimal.

```
df['Time (UT)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time (UT)'], format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f000Z')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
df['Time (UT)'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time (UT)'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S')
```

That line you are using would be modifying your string column or date column into datatime in pandas.

when you want it in a string format of your choice

```
df['Time (UT)'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time (UT)']).dt.strftime("CUSTOM_FORMAT_STRING")
```

for you it would be like

```
df['Time (UT)'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['Time (UT)']).dt.strftime("%Y %m %d %H %M %S")
```